# while runnning jms queue producer sends message and consumer gets message but message is not displayed

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic, producer-consumer, jms-topic

Hi i have java code which has a producer and a consumer. the producer sends the message to a queue and the consumer also gets the message but i do not know why the message is not displayed. I am using activeMQ and as i was not getting the message so i checked in the in the http:/localhost:8161/admin/queues.jsp and there it shows the queue has both producer and consumer But the message is not printed in the command prompt.Please tell me

producer.java

```
import javax.jms.*;
import org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection;
import org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory;

public class Producer {

    private static String url = ActiveMQConnection.DEFAULT_BROKER_URL;
    private static String subject = "test";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JMSException {

        ConnectionFactory connectionFactory =
            new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(url);
        Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
        connection.start();

        Session session = connection.createSession(false,
            Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        Destination destination = session.createQueue(subject);
        MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(destination);

        TextMessage message = session.createTextMessage("this is a g message");
        producer.send(message);

        System.out.println("Sent message '" + message.getText() + "'");
System.out.println( ActiveMQConnection.DEFAULT_BROKER_URL);
        connection.close();
    }
}
```

consumer.java

```
import javax.jms.*;

import org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection;
import org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory;

public class Consumer {

    private static String url = ActiveMQConnection.DEFAULT_BROKER_URL;
    private static String subject = "test";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JMSException {

        ConnectionFactory connectionFactory
            = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(url);
        Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
        connection.start();

        Session session = connection.createSession(false,
            Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

        Destination destination = session.createQueue(subject);
        MessageConsumer consumer = session.createConsumer(destination);
        Message message = consumer.receive();

        if (message instanceof TextMessage) {
            TextMessage textMessage = (TextMessage) message;
            System.out.println("Received message '"
                + textMessage.getText() + "'");
        }
        connection.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: a) please try to format the code nicely: fewer blank lines, remove unnecessary comments, etc.; b) have you tried debugging the code at the consumer? I can't see anything completely wrong at a glance, but can you be sure that the message is a `TextMessage`? Just to be sure ...

Comment: @DaDaDom thanks for replying,yes its a textMesage and i tried to print without using if condition like system.out.println(message); but its not giving any

Comment: I ran your code locally and the message is sent and received with output to the console without any issues.

Comment: @TimBish thanks for replying,yes this is working but sometimes it creates problem in my system. When it does not work then i have to restart the activeMQ server and after that it works. I do not know why this is happening.

Comment: Do you even receive message at the consumer , can you print 'message' object above the If block `if (message instanceof TextMessage)` and let us know ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like the code should work. Not to state the obvious, but are you sure you are running the producer and consumer on the same system? The default broker URL that you're connecting to relies on localhost - so obviously producer and consumer have to be on the same system. Are you sure your stand-alone java applications are connecting to the activeMQ server and creating connections successfully?

If yes, then can you **[connect via jmx](http://fusesource.com/kbs/show/?id=193608-how-to-connect-to-activemq-jmx-using-jconsole-remotely)**  and check the following metrics on the queue:

Enqueue count - shows the number of messages published on the queue -> *confirms whether your producer is publishing*

Dequeue count - shows the # of messages consumed but not acked -> *confirms whether your consumer has consumed*

Dispatch count - shows the # of messages consumed and acked -> *confirms that your consumer has acked, i.e. some exception was not thrown by the consumer while consuming that caused it to fail to ack the message.*

If all is working correctly, these counts should all be equal.

Answer (score -1):

You have to `implement`  `MessageListener`

```
public class Consumer implements MessageListener
```

And you will need to override `onMessage` like this:

```
@Override
    public void onMessage(Message message) {

        if(message instanceof TextMessage){
                  //DO something
   }
}
```

While setting up this consumer you need to do the following:-

```
ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory= new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(ActiveMQConnection.DEFAULT_BROKER_URL);
Connection jmsConnection = connectionFactory.createConnection(userName,passWord);

            jmsConnection.start();
            Session jmsSession =  jmsConnection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);


            Destination destination = jmsSession.createQueue(queuname);

            //Subscribing to a Topic
            MessageConsumer msgConsumer = jmsSession.createConsumer(destination);
            msgConsumer.setMessageListener(this);
```

**EDIT**
This code will keep on listening to messages as soon as they arrive in the queue.
You can add this block inside your main method and this will work.
Hope this helps.

Comment: There's no requirement to use the async message listener style in this example.  The code posted use a blocking sync receive which means it will sit and wait forever for a message to be received.

Comment: @Anubhab thanks for replying,as you can see i am doing everything inside so i can not use "this"
tell me any other way

Comment: What do you mean by "everything inside"?

Comment: @Anubhab i am doing everything inside main

Comment: Thats not a problem.Use 'this'.Is it not connecting even after that? Paste the code inside main and override onMessage. It should work as it is.

Comment: @javalover : ok will get back to you.I guess you are doing something wrong because the code i shared is in production and it works fine man..i am into something now.give me some time.

Comment: @javalover: i tried my code and it works dude. Are you sure you are doing it like this? Can you access http://localhost:8161/admin ??

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25832/discussion-between-anubhab-and-java-lover)

Comment: @Anubhab will this work also when queue is up or down?